# Symfony to set a DateTime in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, symfony, datetime, insert

Question:

In a DB web app, Date/Time field is very common.

When in Symfony, you tried to do either of the follwings:

```
$creationDate=new DateTime();
$record->setCreationDate($creattionDate);
```

This will create a "Object DateTime can't be converted to string" error.

Or:

```
$creationDate=new DateTime();
$datestr=$creationDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$record->setCreationDate($datestr);
```

This will create "Calling method format() on a non-ojbect" error.

Answer (score 1):

In your entity you have to [map](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html) your field with date or datetime type.

@ORM\Column(name="creationDate", type="date", nullable=true)

Answer (score -2):

Solution:

Hack the DateTimeType.php located at: your symfony root/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DateTimeType.php for the function named `convertToDatabaseValue`

Original content:

```
return ($value !== null)
    ? $value->format($platform->getDateTimeFormatString()) : null;
```

It seems Symfony is doing some extra conversion when the parameter is already a string.

Change to:

```
 return ($value !== null)
            ? $value : null;
```

will do the trick.