# symfony2 Date field error

Tags: symfony

```
    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return ($value !== null)
            ? $value->format($platform->getDateTimeFormatString()) : null;
    }
    /**
```

Error: Call to a member function `format()` on string

Comment: $blog->setCreatedAt(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")); i use this and got an error

Comment: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428931/symfony-to-set-a-datetime-in-mysql-database) you can check this

Comment: The date field expects a `\DateTime` object so you should use something like `$blog->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime())`, alternatively don't use the `date` field and just store it as a `string`.